# Custom Header not added through apache cxf OutInterceptor with spring

Tags: spring, cxf, soap-client, interceptor

I have been struggling all day to have a custom SOAP request using spring application context and apache cxf and spring.

My  Interceptor class looks like below

```
public class HttpHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

     public HttpHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.SETUP);
}


@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
       Map<String, List<String>> ietHeaders = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
       List<String> headerItems = new LinkedList<>();

       ietHeaders.put("CustomHeader", Arrays.<String>asList("myheader"));
       message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, ietHeaders);
    }
}
```

WHen I check with [Charlesproxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) it's just the normal request. I am sure I am doing something wrong. At debug time , I can step into handleMessage method but nothing changes. The rest of the code snipet is available on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/9454077)

Can anyone point out the oversight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change Interceptor to `SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor`. For details refer [link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html#SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor)

Hence modify the class as below.

```
public class HttpHeaderInterceptor extends SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor {


    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

        Map<String, List<String>> ietHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> headerItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        headerItems.add("h1");
        headerItems.add("h2");
        headerItems.add("h3");

        ietHeaders.put("CustomHeader", headerItems);
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, ietHeaders);



    }

}
```

Modify your cxf-bean.xml to include interceptor

```
<jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="com.kp.swasthik.soap.interceptor.HttpHeaderInterceptor" />
</jaxws:outInterceptors>
```

The output would be as below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
CustomHeader: h1,h2,h3
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 11:17:57 GMT
```

Comment: you mean the `outInterceptors` should have the bean class `com.whatever.my.package.HttpHeaderInterceptor` rather. I am paying a revisit on your suggestion. Sorry this took me so long to come back